# How can I replace box characters in an Excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, ascii

I'm writing a function that run through all the used cells of a worksheet and replace characters by others (the file come from an extraction and there's some unwanted characters).

Here it is :

```
Sub replaceSpecialCharacters()
    Dim Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "Õ", "ä")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "³", "ü")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "÷", "ö")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, Chr(111), "Ä")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, Chr(220), "Ü")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "Í", "Ö")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "Ó", "à")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "Ú", "é")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "Þ", "è")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "Ô", "â")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "¶", "ô")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, Chr(194), "Â")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, Chr(200), "È")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, Chr(202), "Ê")
        Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "Ù", "œ")
    Next
End Sub
```

It's a bit slow but it works pretty well. My problem is that I can't find a way to replace Ascii "box characters" (▄, ┬, ╚ and ╩ for my case).

I tried to use the Chr() function to put Ascii characters in the vba code but the Excel Ascii character set don't seem to have the ones I'm looking for.

When searching for the Ascii character code on internet I found [this list](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-s-uppercase-ascii-code-83.html) which have the "box characters" but it don't correspond to the Excel list of Ascii characters (you can find it in Insert tab -> Symbols).

Does anyone know if there is a way to reach these "box characters" in the VBA code ?

Comment: Have you tried  Cells.Replace What:="_",

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not bring the original data in properly?

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, so leaving as a comment - `Cells.Replace What:="Õ", Replacement:="ä", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True` will do all replacements on the sheet in one go rather than looking at each cell in turn.  **Edit:**  Just realised that's what @QHarr was getting at. :)

Comment: Put one of the box chars into the cell A1, execute in immediate window: `? AscW(Cells(1, 1))`, you will get the code of the box char, e. g. for `╚` the code is 9562, then all you need to get that char as string is to use `ChrW(9562)`.

Comment: ^^ Two parter. Replace all in one go. Also, does _ get rid of the box characs?

Comment: As Jeeped said I suggest better to fix the cause than to try to correct the symptoms. Where does the data come from? Try to import it correctly instead of fixing the symptoms later.

Comment: Agreeing with @Jeeped, you have [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Perhaps you can find out the character encoding used in the file and apply that [when reading the file](http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinoscript/read-write-utf8/).

Comment: Thanks QHarr and Darren Bartrup-Cook, this syntax is way more efficient. This is effectively an XY problem, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Code will put the Code for the Sign in A1 into A2

```
Cells(2,1).Value = AscW(Cells(1,1).Value)
```

For ▄ this would be 9604.

You can use this Code in your Replace like following:

```
Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, ChrW(9604), "Â")
```

**EDIT:** Some info from @Tom Blodget form a comment:

> It is important to understand that VBA uses the UTF-16 encoding of
> the Unicode character set. AscW and ChrW deal with one UTF-16 code
> unit.
>
> (Asc and Chr cause transcoding between UTF-16 and the user's
> ANSI character encoding at the time the code executes, not ASCII.)

Comment: @Onimanta It is important to understand that VBA uses the UTF-16 encoding of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. `AscW` and `ChrW` deal with one UTF-16 code unit. (`Asc` and `Chr` cause transcoding between UTF-16 and the user's ANSI character encoding at the time the code executes, not ASCII. [ASCII isn't what you think it is anyway.])

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, this works really well. And thanks @TomBlodget for the precision.